# Python/mysolr : Select only one core

Tags: python, solr

On my solr, I have 10 cores (products, sellers, ...).
I need to select only 'products' core with my query :

```
from mysolr import Solr

solr = Solr(version=4)
response = solr.search(q='*:*')
documents = response.documents
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need just to specify the core name on the url :

```
solr = Solr(base_url='http://localhost:8080/solr/products', version=4)
```